# set_author with discord.py throwing a NameError

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm writing a bot with discord.py and while writing an embedded ping command I was encountering some strange errors I haven't found replications of online.

My imports:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import time
```

It's having trouble with this part:

```py
embed = discord.Embed(colour="0xff9999") 
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.channel
    authorID = message.author.id
    if message.content.upper().startswith("T.PING"):
        t1 = time.perf_counter()
        await client.send_typing(channel)
        t2 = time.perf_counter()
        embed.add_field(name="Ping", value=":ping_pong: | <@" + authorID + "> Ponged in {}ms!".format(round((t2-t1)*1000)), inline=True)
        embed.set_author(name=client.user.name, icon=Embed.Empty, icon_url=client.user.avatar_url)
        await client.send_message(channel, embed=embed)
```

When performing my t.ping I get this NameError in the console:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Robin Riezebos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Storage\Desktop\Tapebox.py\Tapebox.py", line 32, in on_message
    embed.set_author(name=client.user.name, icon=Embed.Empty, icon_url=client.user.avatar_url)
NameError: name 'Embed' is not defined
```

I would appreciate some help and an example of how to fix this...

I'm not using a `@client.command` make-up but rather a `client.event` make-up for my commands which changes some aspects but `embed.set_author` should still work.

Edit: added imports list, added rest of if statement in `@client.event`

Comment: Can we see you `import`s?  You may need to resolve it through `discord.Embed.Empty` instead.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I've added more essential information

Answer (score 2):

Notice that above your `on_message` event, you have to use `discord.Embed` to resolve the `Embed` class. You need to either directly import the name `Embed`, with

```
from discord import Embed
```

or refer to `Embed` through the `discord` package

```
embed.set_author(name=client.user.name, icon=discord.Embed.Empty, icon_url=client.user.avatar_url)
```

Though I'm not sure that this is necessary.  I think that `Empty` is the default value, so you should be able to remove the `icon` keyword argument entirely.

Comment: I figured out `icon` isn't a necessary keyword and returns unexpected but I did have to set `url` to `Embed.Empty` after the `from discord import Embed`

Answer (score 2):

The error was firstly because `icon` isn't a keyword. "Embed" wasn't defined, however, "embed" was. The following error is produced on executing with `icon = Embed.Empty` 
`name 'Embed' is not defined` However, when we use `icon = embed.Empty` it produces the following error: `set_author() got an unexpected keyword argument 'icon'` indicating icon wasn't a keyword argument, to begin with.

Secondly, You would have an issue with the `client.avatar_url` as you haven't declared it as a string, i.e `str(client.avatar_url)`. `authorID` in `embed.add_field` would give `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not “int”) to str` for which you have to add `str(authorID)` [As the initial value of `authorID` is an integer]. In Python, values can only be concatenated if they are the same type

```py
@client.event()
async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.channel
    authorID = message.author.id
    if message.content.upper().startswith("T.PING"):
        t1 = time.perf_counter()
        await message.channel.send(channel)
        t2 = time.perf_counter()
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xff9999, title="", description="") 
    embed.add_field(name="Ping", value=":ping_pong: | <@" + str(authorID) + "> Ponged in {}ms!".format(round((t2 - t1)*1000)), inline=True)
    embed.set_author(name=client.user.name, icon_url=str(client.user.avatar_url))
    await message.channel.send(channel, embed=embed)
```

[image: Output]

Check the above image, the following command gives the above output to me. Not sure if this is what you were looking for. Do let me know!

Comment: Please do address the primary error that occurred to the OP `NameError: name 'Embed' is not defined` in addition to your other findings.

Comment: "I did some debugging of the code you sent. And here is what I got. The error was firstly, because "icon" isn't a keyword"

I will add the following to my answer:

 "Embed" wasn't defined, however, "embed" was 

the following error is produced on executing with `icon = Embed.Empty`
 `name 'Embed' is not defined` 

However,  when we use `icon = embed.Empty` it produces the following error:
`set_author() got an unexpected keyword argument 'icon'`
indicating icon wasn't a keyword argument, to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that Embed is not defined. You need to add:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, color=color)
```

Where to put it? Here

```
embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, color=color
embed.add_field(name="Ping", value=":ping_pong: | <@" + authorID + "> Ponged in {}ms!".format(round((t2-t1)*1000)), inline=True)
        embed.set_author(name=client.user.name, icon=Embed.Empty, icon_url=client.user.avatar_url)
        await client.send_message(channel, embed=embed)
```

Good Luck!